# DataSourceUtils.getConnection vs DataSource.getConnection

Tags: java, spring

I have datasource bean initialized in the spring context. I wonder what way should be used? Why I just can not write dataSource.getConnection()?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is one important difference: `dataSource.getConnection()` always returns a new connection obtained from the dataSource or connection pool. `DataSourceUtils.getConnection()` checks if there is an active transaction for the current thread. If there is one, it will return connection with this transaction. If there is none it will behave exactly the same way as `dataSource.getConnection()`.

You need to be careful when using `DataSourceUtils.getConnection()`. If it returns connection for the active transaction it means someone else will be closing it since it's the responsibility of whoever opened the transaction. On the other hand, if it returns a brand new connection from the dataSource it's you who should commit/rollback/close it.

Comment: So if I have running transaction and get connection through `dataSource.getConnection()` that connection will not be bound to the current transaction?

Comment: @mishanesterenko No, dataSource.getConnection() will always return a 'fresh' connection directly from database or from the pool with no active transaction.

Comment: From the javadoc of `DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection()` it states: "Close the given Connection, obtained from the given DataSource, if it is not managed externally (that is, not bound to the thread)." That would suggest that it is always safe to call this method after you are done using the connection (obtained from `DataSourceUtils.getConnection()` ) and requires no knowledge about whether the connection participated in an actual transaction or not.

Comment: 10 years later and still helpful. Good job @mrembisz.

Answer (score 3):

[`DataSourceUtils#getConnection()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getConnection%28javax.sql.DataSource%29) pretty clearly documents why you may want to use it: in particular, it uses the Spring JDBC exception hierarchy as opposed to raw SQL exceptions and it will participate in Spring's transaction management facility. If you don't need either of those two features, you can just use `DataSource#getConnection()` and get on with your code.

Comment: So if I have running transaction and get connection through `dataSource.getConnection()` that connection will not be bound to the current transaction?