# Is there some trick to update an Oracle CLOB with Mybatis 3?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, mybatis, clob

I am updating a CLOB column in my Oracle database.  The parameterized SQL looks like it is executing correctly without error, but when I run a select to see the change, it has not been updated.  Note:  MyBatis 3 is built using JDBC Parameterized Queries, so those rules also apply.

MyBatis Mapping:

```
<update id="updateRSA103RequestData" parameterType="com.company.domain.RSA103XMLData" flushCache="true">
        update
        RSA_SUBMIT_DATA
        set TXLIFE_REQUEST = #{request}
        where RSA_SUBMIT_QUEUE_ID = #{id}
</update>
```

Runtime Logs:

> 2012-07-13 12:35:26,728 DEBUG Connection:Thread main:   - ooo
>   Connection Opened 2012-07-13 12:35:26,837 DEBUG
>   PreparedStatement:Thread main:   - ==>  Executing: update
>   RSA_SUBMIT_DATA set TXLIFE_REQUEST = ? where RSA_SUBMIT_QUEUE_ID = ?
>   2012-07-13 12:35:26,837 DEBUG PreparedStatement:Thread main:   - ==>
>   Parameters: testasdfasdf(String), 51(Integer) 2012-07-13 12:35:27,024
>   DEBUG Connection:Thread main:   - xxx Connection Closed

Select query after change:

```
select *
from RSA_SUBMIT_DATA
where RSA_SUBMIT_QUEUE_ID = 51

RSA_SUBMIT_QUEUE_ID | TXLIFE_REQUEST  | TXLIFE_RESPONSE
51             | originalString   | resultString
```

Mapper invocation:

```
SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
try {
    log.debug("autoCommit: " + sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().getEnvironment().getDataSource().getConnection().getAutoCommit());
    PolicyTransactionMapper policyTransactionDAO = sqlSession
                .getMapper(PolicyTransactionMapper.class);
    RSA103XMLData xmlData = new RSA103XMLData();
    xmlData.setId(rsaSubmitQueueID);
    xmlData.setRequest(request);
    policyTransactionDAO.updateRSA103RequestData(xmlData);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to commit the transaction?  Can you add the code for the Mapper and SqlSession invocations.

Comment: Auto-commit is enabled.  I will add the mapper call.

Comment: Okay, even though it was set to auto-commit, I tried sqlSession.commit() to see if it made any difference, and it did.  Problem solved.  but I still don't understand why it didn't work before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your SqlSession is opened with auto commit.

Per [MyBatis User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf), to use auto commit, try.

> SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(true);

Also,  your log statement is actually opening a new connection.  See [DataSourceUtils.getConnection vs DataSource.getConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642643/datasourceutils-getconnection-vs-datasource-getconnection)

This will probably return a different connection than what your mapper is using anyways.