# How to properly close datasource connection?

Tags: java, mysql, datasource

I have this class but Im not sure on how to properly close connection because Im still having this error even though I only have 3 users logged in but with multiple sql queries.

> ```
> > com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
> > Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from
> > server: "Too many connections"
> ```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao
{

    DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
            return this.dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
    {
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }


    public boolean isValidUser(String username, String password) throws SQLException
    {       
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        boolean rt = false;
        try{
            PasswordEncryptor pws = new PasswordEncryptor();
            String encryptedPass = pws.encrypt(password);

            String query = "Select count(1) from userdetails where username = ? and password = ?";
            pstmt = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, username);
            pstmt.setString(2, encryptedPass);
            resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()){
                    rt =  (resultSet.getInt(1) > 0);
            }
            else{
                rt = false;
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally{
        resultSet.close();
        pstmt.close();
        dataSource.getConnection().close();
    }

        return rt;  
    }
}
```

SpringConfiguration.xml

```
    <bean name="userDao" class="com.spring.acadconnect.services.UserDaoImpl">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
   </bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acadconnect" />

    <property name="username" value="root" />

    <property name="password" value="" />

</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

Notice that you're calling `.getConnection()` multiple times. Although the documentation could be clearer on this front [`DataSource.getConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection--) actually *opens* a new connection (as opposed to returning an existing one) thus you need to close each instance returned from that method.

As `.getConnection()` creates a new instance every time it's called this line is a connection leak, since it's not closing the connection being returned:

```
pstmt = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
```

And this line wastefully opens a new connection only to immediately close it:

```
dataSource.getConnection().close();
```

---

It looks like you're trying to open and close a separate connection for each invocation of `isValidUser()` (since you're closing the connection at the end of that method call). Even if you fix the leak described above, that's not how connections are intended to be used. Instead you should share one connection (or a small number of them) across your application. So when your program starts up you open such a connection, and once *the whole program* no longer needs the connection (often shortly before terminating) you close it.

This sort of behavior is commonly implemented by [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), where you construct your connections and other resources and then pass them into whatever objects need them - this decouples resource management from the code that uses those resources. As a simplistic example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  DataSource dataSource = createDataSource();
  try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
    runProgram(connection);
  }
}


/**
 * this method doesn't need to worry about closing the Connection,
 * it trusts that its caller will be responsible for that.
 */
private static void runProgram(Connection connection) {
  // ...
}
```

As a rule of thumb, objects should only be responsible for closing objects they construct, and should avoid closing objects they are passed. In your current code `UserDaoImpl` is opening the connection, so it should be responsible for closing it, but I'm suggesting passing in the `Connection` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

`dataSource.getConnection()` will always return you a new connection, therefore you are not closing the connection that you think. You must use `DataSourceUtils.getConnection()` to get the active connection of the current thread or else store the reference returned like conn = dataSource.getConnection() and the call `conn.close()`

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Reference [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9642643/113632) which describes `DataSource` vs. `DataSourceUtils` in more detail. Note that if you use `DataSourceUtils` then `UserDaoImpl` should not be calling `Connection.close()` (but some part of the application still needs to manage closing the connections).

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.

```
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

and later when you don't need connection to database anymore just close using

```
conn.close();
```

Update:

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

try {
    // ur code
}
catch (SQLException ex) 
{
    // Exception handling
} 
finally 
{
    if (rs != null) 
{
    if (ps != null) {
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { out.print(e)} // This will print exception to help better
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { out.print(e)}
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem now is that connection is not being closed when I deploy it on tomcat server using war file but when Im running the project on my IDE, the connection is properly closing. Im checking the "show processlist" in mysql.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Try this if you are not already using try catch statement please check my updated answer.